# VB6 permission denied error while making the exe. Compiler stops at a line creating instance

Tags: vb6, barcode

VB6 throws Compile error: Permission denied error while stopping at a line 'Set Barcode1 = New Axbarcode'

axbarcode.ocx exists in System32 folder and SysWOW64 folder. It has also been registered.

PS. Running VB6 on Windows 7

Thanks in advance

Comment: Reboot.  I'm not kidding.

Comment: Could it be that OCX is being used by another app?  Before you reboot you could try restarting the development environment and compile.

Comment: I have tried reboots without any success.

Comment: The OCX has objects related to barcode generation feature used in the project that I'm trying to make exe of. I am very sure no other apps in the system uses that OCX. It did work without any issues on Win XP. I'm facing this issue after migrating to Windows 7.

Comment: If you try to compile it to another filename, such as "test.ocx" does that make any difference?

Comment: Two things: 1. Are you running VB6 IDE as Administrator? 2. Are you missing licensing for your Barcode control?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalled the component and it works.